# How many different varieties of pizza can be made if you have the following choices:

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many different varieties of pizza can be made if you have the following choice: small medium, large; thin, hand tossed, pan; and $12$ toppings (cheese is an automatic), from which you may select from $0-12$.

What I did for this was $3C1 \cdot 3C1 \cdot 13C1$.  However, I know my answer is incorrect.  Is it because $13C1$ is not the proper was of expressing the different ways toppings could be chosen?

Comment: That is where you made your error.  You can choose any subset of those $12$ toppings.

Comment: Where did the $13$ come from?

Comment: @BrianTung  I suspect joe looked at how many toppings were included rather than which subset of toppings was included.

Answer (score 1):

You made your error when you concluded that there were $13$ ways of selecting $0 - 12$ toppings.  It is the subset of toppings that are included rather than the number of toppings that matters.  For instance, knowing that two toppings have been selected does not tell you whether those toppings are mushrooms and olives or pepperoni and anchovies.

You are correct that there are three ways of selecting the size and three ways of selecting the way the pizza is prepared.  Since you can select any subset of the $12$ toppings, including none, the number of varieties of pizza is 
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}\cdot 2^{12}$$
The reason the number of subsets of $12$ toppings is $2^{12}$ is that there are two options for each topping, to include it or not to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to have no toppings, any one topping, any two toppings, any three toppings... or twelve toppings.   That is, any subset of the twelve toppings (including the empty set).

But look at it another way: For each topping you have a choice whether to include it or not.   That is twelve independent choices with two options.

That is: $2^{12}$ way to select toppings.

Answer (score 0):

Using the first part of your answer, the solution can be expressed as follows where $n$ is the number of toppings:

$$\binom{3}{1}^2*\sum_{n=0}^{12}\binom{12}{n}$$

It should make sense because for each possible topping option, there are $\binom{3}{1}$ sizes and $\binom{3}{1}$ types of pizza. Therefore, we must look at the number of topping arrangements. There are $\binom{12}{0}$ for no toppings, $\binom{12}{1}$ for $1$, etc. Therefore, we have the binomial summation given mulitiplied by $\binom{3}{1}^2$ to also account for size and type.

**Ergo, your final answer should be $36,864$ possible pizzas.**